# how to create a bidirectional LSTM model with three features: wind speed, time of day, and power. target variable is power

Tags: python, lstm

```
ws_data = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (num_samples, timesteps, 1)) # wind speed feature
tod_data = np.random.uniform(0, 24, (num_samples, timesteps, 1)) # time of day feature
power_data = np.random.normal(5000, 1000, (num_samples, 1)) # power output
```

when I create input data from the above data then the below value error
ValueError: all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 2 has 2 dimension(s)